# Display data from localStorage cache, then update with AJAX result from service

Tags: ajax, angularjs, caching, local-storage

I have a RESTful web service that returns a list of products. I have an Angular app that calls this service via Ajax. What I want to do is:

- check whether the list of products is in localStorage, if so, display this on the screen, then make the Ajax call in the background and refresh the screen when this service returns.

Effectively, I want a way to first load and display from localStorage (my cache), and then replace it with the latest data from the service once it returns (and update the cache).

I want to first load and display the data from localStorage because if the user is offline then obviously the Ajax request won't complete and I want this app to work when the user doesn't have an internet connection.

How would you implement this on the Angular side? I was looking at $q and promises but wasn't sure how I could get it to 'resolve' twice...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a simple service that loads a file from your server to say the app is online, until that file is loaded your app is offline so you won't make the Ajax call in the first place, maybe have the service poll your server given the importance of knowing the status throught your app session.